# A bit of help with cron script please

Tags: server, scripts, cron

I would like to set a cron on an ubuntu server to download a file to a specific location. How would I go about this?

For example once a day I would like my ubuntu server to look for a file on a website then download it and overwrite the existig file if present.

something like

wget http://myexternalwebsite.com/downloads/filename
cp filename /etc/myfolder/filename

ANy help would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Have you tried the [CronHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)? Everything is explained there very well. Also a GUI tool is available.

Answer (score 1):

Very rough .. no error checking etc, but I'll leave that as a learning exercise :)

Create this in /home/yourUsername and call it downloader.sh (as an example) and make it executable (chmod +x /home/yourUsername/downloader.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
wget http://myexternalwebsite.com/downloads/filename
cp /tmp/filename /etc/myfolder/filename
```

To download the file at midnight every 24 hours, add to your crontab (crontab -e)

```
0 0 * * * /home/yourUsername/downloader.sh
```

Comment: Fantastic just the starting point I was looking for!

Comment: Excellent - if you're happy with it and it's answered your question, can you mark the response as accepted pls - I'll earn a few points off it. Ta.